# Blackmagic Design Intensity Shuttle is recognized by hardware but not by software.

Tags: drivers, usb, video, video-capture-card

### Problem

I try to use my **Blackmagic Design Intensity Shuttle** on a **Zotac ZBOX** running **Ubuntu.** It seems, that the system recognizes the device on an USB 3 port, but the software doesn’t.

When I list the usb ports, the system recognizes the capture card

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1edb:bd3b Blackmagic design Intensity Shuttle
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

But when I start the supplied software Desktop Video Utility, I get the error message:

> No Desktop Video Device Detected.
>   Please check that your product is connected via Thunderbolt, USB3 or PCIe and is powered on.

or Media Express:

> Blackmagic hardware could not be found in your system. 
>   Please check the installation.

### Disclaimer

So, I don’t really know what to do now. I have to confess, that my knowledge about Ubuntu is very limited.

But at least I tried the whole process with several versions of the software supplied by the manufacturer. After that I tried to learn how to reset the USB ports and found a Skript written in C, which seems to work fine (at least it doesn’t break anything) but without the wanted result.

***So, every advise is welcome!***

### Setup

#### Hardware

Computer

[Zotac ZBOX CI320 nano](https://www.zotac.com/de/product/mini_pcs/ci320-nano-windows-81-bing)
Intel N2930 (quad core, 1.83 GHz, up to 2.16 GHz)
4 GB memory

Capture Card

Blackmagic Design Intensity Shuttle USB 3.0
(external)

#### Software

Operation System

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Drivers and supplied Applications

[Desktop Video Utility by Blackmagic Design](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/intensity)
tried Versions 10.4, 10.4.3 and 10.5